# Jenkinsfile archive step: allow missing artifacts

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Under the regular UI defined jobs I can select *"Do not fail build if archiving returns nothing"*. How do I achieve the equivalent in pipeline code?

E.g. currently I have something along these lines:

```
archive 'screenshots/**', 'build/test/results/*.xml'
```

and it is OK if there are no screenshots since there would be none if all tests pass.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use the new `archiveArtifacts` command, like this:

```
archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'screenshots/**,build/test/results/*.xml', allowEmptyArchive: true
```

Find the complete documentation of this command at https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/#archiveartifacts-archive-the-artifacts

Comment: Can anyone provide a reference for this command?  It's not listed at https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ as of 2017 June 27 and a quick search only seems to turn up mention in a couple tutorials but not definitive reference.

Comment: Yes it is really strange, it seems to be missing! Found this issue about it; https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37322